# Extending the current link on a button click in html

Tags: html, url, button

Let's say that the url of the current page is localhost:3000/index/a and I want to get to page with url localhost:3000/index/a/b. If I use the following button on the page with url localhost:3000/index/a:

`<button onclick="./b">Go to next page</button>`

then the page that is accessed is localhost:3000/index/b and not localhost:3000/index/a/b like I wanted. Is there any solution without using an absolute address that includes the current "a" page? I know I could do `onclick="./a/b"` but I would like it to be more direct, without specifying /a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't.

If you use a relative path, then it will be appended to the last `/` in the current path.

There is nothing that will append to the whole path.

You need to specify (at least) the `a` portion. (You *can* calculate that with JavaScript but then you become dependant on JS).

---

Alternatively, you could design your URL structure so the user visits `/index/a/` instead of `/index/a` in the first place.

Comment: Well that's annoying, I really thought there must have been an easy solution hiding somewhere... Thanks for the information.